# lapply to extract rows from list

Tags: r, subset, lapply

I have the following question:
I have a list (L1) with two parts and each 4 identical variables.
The variable 4 is also the name of the part of the list. e.g. $a = a

```
a <- data.frame(V1=c("a","b","c"), V2=c(4,7,9), V3=1:3, V4=c("a","a","a"))
b <- data.frame(V1=c("d","e","f"), V2=c(10,14,16), V3=1:3, V4=c("b","b","b"))
L1 <- list(a=a, b=b)
L1

$a
V1    V2    V3   V4
a     4     1    a
b     7     2    a
c     9     3    a
$b
V1    V2    V3   V4
d     10     1    b
e     14     2    b
f     16     3    b
```

I would like to extract the rows of each part of the list with V3==2. If there is no row in the list with this value V1 to V3 should be extracted with NA and V4 should contain the name of the part of the list.

In the example the outcome should look like this:

```
V1   V2    V3   V4
b    7     2    a
e    14    2    b
```

If I select a value e.g. V3==4 then my result should look like this:

```
V1   V2    V3   V4
<NA>  <NA>  <NA>    a
<NA>  <NA>  <NA>    b
```

I can extract a column with 
`unlist(lapply(L1, "[",3))` but I can't figure out how to extract rows which have a certain value in a variable.
I also tried to combine lapply with the subset function, but this didn't work for me.
Thank's for your help!

Comment: Write your own function `foo` which takes a data.frame `df` and a value for V3 (let's call it `v`). So write `foo(df, v)` to return what you want. Then, simply apply it to the list: `lapply(L1, FUN=foo, 3)`. Note that the `3` here is passed as the second argument of foo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. The first command returns a list, the second one converts it to a data frame. If the value is not in the data, it returns NA (for the list) or a row of NAs (for the df).

```
l <- lapply(L1, function(x) {i <- which(x$V3 == 2)
                         if (length(i) > 0) x[i, ]
                         else NA })

df <- rbind(l[[1]], l[[2]])
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer! This works great. Just one more question: How can I achieve that the function returns NA when a value is not found?

Comment: I'll put the answer in my original answer

Comment: Thank's so much for your help. Your solution solved my problem and I learned quite a bit!

Answer (score 2):

You can also bind_rows with dplyr

```
list(a = a, b = b) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "source") %>%
  filter(V2 == 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could create a function using `data.table`.  We rbind the `list` elements with `rbindlist`, grouped by 'V4', `if` the 'V3' is not equal to the given value, we return the NA elements (`.SD[.N+1]`) or else return the Subset of Data.table (`.SD[tmp]`).

```
library(data.table)
f1 <- function(lst, val){
        rbindlist(lst)[, {tmp <- V3==val
                   if(!any(tmp)) .SD[.N+1]
                   else .SD[tmp]},
                           by = V4][, names(lst[[1]]), with=FALSE]
  }

f1(L1, 4)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1: NA NA NA  a
#2: NA NA NA  b

f1(L1, 3)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1:  c  9  3  a
#2:  f 16  3  b

f1(L1, 2)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1:  b  7  2  a
#2:  e 14  2  b
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer and your help! I used the answer from toldo. But I will try your solution also. Thank's!

Comment: @Carlos No problem.  Glad to help you.